# Pandas - first n maximum values groupby pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe as below:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    'b': [3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1]
})
```

Which gives me

```py
>>> df
    a   b
0   1   3
1   1   2
2   1   1
3   1   4
4   1   2
5   2   1
6   2   2
7   2   2
8   2   1
```

I want to **group the dataframe by column `a`**, and return **first N maximum values** from column `b` of each group, **ordered descending by that maximum value**.

### What have I done?

**Let's consider I only want first two maximum values**, I've done the following:

1. Sort the dataframe by both columns in descending order
2. Get first two values
3. Since these values are order ascending, sort another time in descending order

```py
df = df.sort_values(['a', 'b'], ascending=False)
df = df.groupby('a').nth([0,1])
df = df.sort_values(['a', 'b'], ascending=False).reset_index()
```

Which gives me

```py
>>> df
    a   b
0   2   2
1   2   2
2   1   4
3   1   3
```

**The output Works fine**, but it's not the efficient way to do this.

I have also tried `nlargest` function, but it's not helping, because it drops other columns and returns only the `b` column.

```py
df = df.groupby('a')['b'].nlargest(2)
```

Which gives me

```py
>>> df
0    2
1    2
2    4
3    3
Name: b, dtype: int64
```

**What is the best way to do this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Sort` the values by column `b` then `group` the dataframe and aggregate using [`head(n)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html) to select the first `n` rows of each group

```
df.sort_values('b', ascending=False).groupby('a').head(2)
```

---

```
   a  b
3  1  4
0  1  3
6  2  2
7  2  2
```

Comment: Not a bad solution thanks. let's see if there is more straightforward way to do this or not. I'll accept the best answer by tomorrow

Comment: @Tabaraei Not a problem. By the way you can reduce the code typing a little bit using a variation of the above approach `df.sort_values('b').groupby('a').tail(2)`